# DynamoDB transaction conflicts detection

Tags: transactions, amazon-dynamodb

I'm running an application writing into multiple tables in DynamoDB. I want for either all the operations to succeed or all them fail, so I'm using transactionality.

I have 3 tables in DynamoDB:

**EntityA:**
userId: partition key, requestId: sort key,
count: simple count value

**EntityB** and **EntityC**:
userId: partition key, requestId + eventId: sort key

Assuming every execution receives a different event with a unique eventId, EntityB and EntityC will always be new records, while EntityA will may be updated.

The process I'm running may have concurrent operations for the same user and requestId, but it's not frequent. However, I want to make sure in case it happens, only one of the process fails, since I want to prevent ghost updates.

Here is the minimized version of the code:

```
TransactionWriteRequest transactionWriteRequest = new TransactionWriteRequest();
Optional<EntityA> optionalEntityA = dynamoDbMapper.query(entityA.class, queryExpression).stream().findFirst();
transactionWriteRequest.addPut(createNewEntityB());
transactionWriteRequest.addPut(createNewEntityC());
if (optionalEntityA.isPresent()){
    transactionWriteRequest.addPut(optionalEntityA.get().incrementCount());
} else {
    transactionWriteRequest.addPut(createNewEntityA());
}
dynamoDbMapper.transactionWrite(transactionWriteRequest);
```

As far as I could read, there is no way of explicitly starting a transaction using DynamoDbMapper API. And also there is no way of grouping both read and write operations in the same transaction. The transaction starts and finishes when *transactionWrite* is executed.

Let's say record in EntityA does not exist yet for the combination of a given(consumerId, requestId). If two concurrent executions try to create them at the same time, one of them will fail due to the uniqueness of the primary key, right?

Now, my question is for the updates:

1. Let's say record EntityA exists already with (consumerId=1, requestId=1).
2. Now we receive two concurrent events with the same primary key(consumerId=1, requestId=1).
3. Execution 1 reads EntityA (line 2)
4. Just after that, execution 2 commits its transaction successfully.

What will happen when execution 1 tries to commit the transaction? Will DynamoDB detect that execution 2 has modified EntityA after it has read the value and throw an exception? Or will it finish the execution overriding the value written by execution 2?

I know DynamoDB supports OptimisticLocking for updating a record only if it was not modified before. However, it is not supported for transactional operations, so I would like to know if DynamoDB transactions are able to detect these conflicts or not.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What will happen when execution 1 tries to commit the transaction? Will DynamoDB detect that execution 2 has modified EntityA after it has read the value and throw an exception? Or will it finish the execution overriding the value written by execution 2?

- It will override it.

> I know DynamoDB supports OptimisticLocking for updating a record only if it was not modified before. However, it is not supported for transactional operations, so I would like to know if DynamoDB transactions are able to detect these conflicts or not.

- You can still use optimisitc locking with DynamoDB TransactWriteItems, you just can't do so while using DynamoDB Mapper client. You will need to do so with the low level client.
- Transactions will handle conflicts, as in if two transactions occur on the same item concurrently, one will succeed and one will fail. However, in your example, you aren't talking about conflicts of writes, but rather reading/writing stale data. In which case you should use the low level client and implement optimistic locking.